# Как сделать, чтобы программа на C, запуская другую программу, передала функции

Tags: linux, c

Как сделать, чтобы программа на C, запуская другу программу, передала функции. Я хочу написать таким образом, чтобы программа на Linux была запущена вот так:

```sh
./runner programm.out
```

А в `programm.out` написан вот такой код:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int getCalc(int a, int b);

int main() {
  gatCalc(5, 7);
}
```

А в программе `runner` типа такого:

```c
int getCalc(int a, int b) {
  return a+b;
}
```

Comment: Можно начать с изучения основ языка. Например, узнать, для чего в самом верху написано include <stdio.h>.

Comment: @Эникейщик Я в пример написал!

Comment: Я всё-таки настоятельно рекомендую узнать, для чего это пишется. Возможно, после этого вопрос отпадет 

Comment: @Эникейщик ммм :|

Comment: Лучше не надо, а сразу перейти к изучению процесса линковки. И вообще, как собираются эти ваши бинарники.

Comment: Так `program.out` — это бинарник или исходник? Не совсем ясно из вашего описания.

Comment: @0andriy Бинарник

Answer (score 0):

> Как сделать, чтобы программа на C, запуская другу программу, передала
>   функции.

Насколько я понял, здесь необходимо выполнить два действия:

1. Запустить из программы *runner* исполняемый модуль   *programm.out*
2. В программе *programm.out* выполнить вызов функции, определённой в модуле *runner*

Я думаю, что с первым пунктом особых вопросов не возникает - стандартная связка *fork/execve* решает эту задачу.

Насчёт второго пункта сложнее. В *Linux* (насколько мне известно) существует только два способа доступа к объектам из другого модуля:

1. Статическая компоновка
2. Динамическая компоновка - shared object (*.so)

В любом случае **связь** между двумя разными модулями организует **линкер** - компоновщик. Link так и переводится: связь.

Для организации **статической** компоновки необходимо создать исходный модуль *getCalc.c*, скомпилировать его в объектный файл *getCalc.o* и прикомпоновать к обоим модулям - *runner* и *programm.out*

Для организации **динамической** компоновки надо исходный модуль *getCalc.c* скомпилировать с ключом *-fPIC* и указать линкеру, при компоновке модулей *runner* и *programm.out* созданную динамическую библиотеку ключом *-l*

Более подробно этот процесс описан тут: http://staff.mmcs.sfedu.ru/~ulysses/IT/C++/using_gcc.html

Comment: И третий способ. Как по-вашему работают плагины?

Comment: @0andriy *Как по-вашему работают плагины?* - я думаю. это будет очень интересно TS!  Расскажите ему...

Comment: У меня две программы скомпилированно runner и programm.out

Comment: @Redis "У меня две программы скомпилированно" - что это означает? То, что программы **уже** скомпилированы и Вы никак не можете изменить исполняемые модули? Но тогда не понятен смысл вопроса "Как сделать...". Если ничего нельзя сделать - тогда зачем спрашивать?!

А если Вы всё-таки **можете** перекомпиллировать эти модули, то ответ я уже писал: нужно вынести функцию *getCalc()* в отдельный модуль, создать из неё объектный (или разделяемый) файл и прилинковать его как к *runner* так и к *programm.out*.

Comment: @Sergey другой вопрос, как добавить библиотеку во времч работы программы (инжектировани) в linux

Comment: @Redis Если библиотека оформлена как динамический объект, то существует два варианта. Первый - отдать всё на управление линкера. В этом случае, необходимо при линковке ВЫЗЫВАЮЩЕГО модуля задать ключ компоновки *-l<Подключаемая библиотека> В командной строке этот ключ обязательно должен стоять **после** вызывающего модуля.  Второй вариант - самостоятельная подгрузка необходимой разделяемой библиотеки. Дело это не шибко простое, поэтому я не буду его тут описывать. Подробности можете посмотреть тут: https://webhamster.ru/mytetrashare/index/mtb0/938